# Reputation points vs Captcha: spam / bots prevention

Tags: discussion

Being an passive user of stackoverflow.com for many years -
This service *saved my day several times*.

**Great service, many thanks for it.**

I created a new account here.

Why the system of reputation points prevents me to write responses?

I wonder to know why a captcha isn't implemented instead.

(Please note I don't have any new question related to software development now).

Comment: Hi tobias_k., thanks for that speedy response. Well, I'm not allowed to post to Meta too.

Comment: What kind of responses are you talking about? Comments? Questions/Answers?

Comment: Hi Ivar, I meant comments.

Comment: In that case [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174) answers your question.